# Not able to save model to gs bucket using torch.save()

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pytorch

I am trying to save a PyTorch model to my google cloud bucket but it is always showing a "FileNotFoundError error".

I already have a gs bucket and the file path I am providing is also correct. My code is running on a GCP notebook instance.

```py
path = "gs://bucket_name/model/model.pt"
torch.save(model,path)
```

It would really help me if someone tries to upload a model to gs bucket and let me know if you could or not? It would also help me if you shared the right way to put models into gs bucket using `torch.save()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `torch.save` in a slightly different way. As written in [the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.save.html#torch.save), the `f` parameter of `torch.save` can either be a simple string or `os.PathLike` object containing a file name, or a file-like object for which the `write` and `flush` methods are implemented. We can use the latter to save the model directly to a Google Cloud bucket:

```py
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client("bucket_name")
bucket = storage_client.bucket("bucket_name")
blob = bucket.blob("model/model.pt")
with blob.open("wb", ignore_flush=True) as f:
    torch.save(obj, f)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import gcsfs
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project = '<enter your gc project>')
with fs.open("gs://bucket_name/"+f'model/model.pt', 'wb') as f:
    torch.save(model, f)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I like this answer, from a python standpoint, it looks self explanatory